# Python list comprehension to fill dict used as mutliset

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I need to create a multiset tracking the frequencies of characters appearing in a given string. I wanted to implement this using dict comprehensions, but what I tried:

```
mySet = {letter : mySet.get(letter, 0) + 1 for letter in myStr}
```

Did not seem to work... as `mySet.get(letter, 0)` always seems to return 0. Is there another way to accomplish this simple task without resorting to loops?

Comment: `mySet` is not set until **after** the dictionary comprehension completes. You can't reference the dictionary-being-built from inside the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: There is a standard type for this in the Python standard library: [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): * The `Counter` class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.*, so use `mySet = Counter(myStr)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Counter

```
from collections import Counter

Counter('Hello World')
```

This returns

```
Counter({' ': 1, 'H': 1, 'W': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1})
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.